# Can she give the zakaah of her wealth to her brother who is sponsored by her father?

Tags: practical-islam, zakat

My brother got married about a year ago and is expecting a baby soon.  Is it permissible for me to give him the zakaah of my wealth to help him with the expenses for the baby? Please note that he works, but his income is limited and is barely enough for him and his wife. They are living with my father , who provides them with accommodation and food. I already know that my father will cover all the necessary costs for the baby, but I want to reduce the burden for my father. Is it permissible for me to give my brother the zakaah on my and my husband's wealth, with my husband's agreement.

Answer (score 2):

So long as what he is getting from your father is sufficient, then he is regarded as being independent of means as a result of that, so it is not permissible to give him zakat.

But if his father cannot afford to spend on him, or refuses to do so, or if what he gives him is not sufficient to meet his needs, then in that case it is permissible to give zakat to him.